# How to retrieve a specific item from a website, and bring it into C# as a string or integer?

Tags: c#

I would like to parse the html below to extract the number inside the `h1` tag. How would I be able to achieve this?

The html code containing the number is as follows -

```
<a id="container">
    <div id="top" style="height: 775px;">
        <span class="texture"></span>
        <h1 style="margin-top: 369px; margin-bottom: 369px; opacity: 1;">6</h1>
    </div>
</a>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can extract it from this json `object`

http://www.howmanypeopleareinspacerightnow.com/peopleinspace.json

At the very top you can see

```
"number" : 6
```

Comment: How would I bring that into my C# program, and display it in a label though